# How to compare values in a 1d array to a 2d array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm creating a lottery program for use within c++ and am wondering this code would work to compare the numbers

```
do
{
    for (int Num = 0; Num < 6; Num++) {
        if (RandomNumber[Num] == Numbers[Games][Num]) {
            cout << "A Number matches" << Numbers[Games][Num] << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Bad Luck, Try Again Next Time" << Numbers[Games][Num] << endl;
        }
    }
    Games = Games - 1;
} while (Games > -1);
```

Whenever I attempt to run this code, it doesn't compare the  numbers correctly and the only issue I can think of is that it isn't possible to run the code to do what I want it to do. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: attempted it as all the code runs, however just doesnt do exactly what i want as it says there are no matches, even if there are matching numbers

Comment: Add `std::cout << RandomNumber[Num] << " " << Numbers[Games][Num] << std::endl;` before the `if`, then you can see what's being compared to what on each iteration.

Comment: Try moving `Games = Games -1` outside the for-loop.

Comment: Your indentation is really weird.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check all Numbers[Games] not only on Numbers[Games][Num] but I only guess. I don't know your whole idea. I think you should do something like that:

```
do
{
    for (int Num=0; Num<6; Num++)
    {
        bool exist = false;
        for( int i = 0; i < 6; ++i ) 
        {
             if (RandomNumber[Num] == Numbers[Games][i]) exist = true;
        }
        if (exist)           
        {
            cout<<"A Number matches"<<RandomNumber[Num]<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
           cout<<"Bad Luck, Try Again Next Time"<<RandomNumber[Num]<<endl;
        }
    }
    Games = Games - 1;
}
while (Games>-1);
}
```

I didn't test this code. It's not the best performance solution.

Comment: I think his while loop already iterating over  games...  So extra loop not required

Comment: I don't think. If he want to check if number RandomNumber[num] exist in array Numbers[Games] then he need to iterate all numbers in array Numbers[Games].

Comment: im trying to create a lottery program so what i want the compare to do is check if a number in the random number array matches with any of the numbers in the Number 2d array which is the player input into the program

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to match an entire row, your current logic does not seem to be very good.
This is a slightly modified version of what @Adam Folwarczny posted.

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void)
{
    int Numbers [] [6] = 
    {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12},
        {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18},
        {19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24}
    };

    int RandomNumber [] = {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18} ;

    int nGames = sizeof (Numbers) / sizeof (Numbers [0]) ;
    int nNumbers = sizeof (RandomNumber) / sizeof (RandomNumber [0]) ;

    // This assumes order matters.
    for (int i = 0; i < nGames; ++i) {

        bool bWin = true ;

        for (int j = 0; j < nNumbers; ++j) {
            if (RandomNumber [j] != Numbers [i] [j]) {
                bWin = false ;
                break ;
            }
        }

        if (bWin == true) {
            std::cout << "Player " << (i + 1) << " won!" << std::endl ;
        }

        else {
            std::cout << "Player " << (i + 1) << " lost!" << std::endl ;
        }
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```